# Running a bash script in nodejs application deployed on amazon ECS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I have a nodejs application that is deployed on Amazon ECS. I have setup codepipeline to automatically build and deploy the application. The application is dockerized and is deployed on a ubuntu machine. The application is working fine. However, there is a requirement to run a shell script from within the application. I am calling the shell script using await exec(path/to/shellscript). However, I keep getting the following error:

```
2021-02-08 17:19:48FAILED: undefined, 4e9d8424-3cfd-4f35-93cb-fac886b1c4918fc9f680cfea45ec813db787f8b8380a
2021-02-08 17:19:48/bin/sh: src/myApp/myScript.bash: not found
```

I have tried giving it permission using chmod but I keep getting errors still.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the script that I am running calls an executable created to run on Ubuntu. However, the docker image is an alpine Linux distribution. The issue has been explained in detail here:
[Why can't I run a C program built on alpine on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341750/why-cant-i-run-a-c-program-built-on-alpine-on-ubuntu)